# How can I enable the lockscreen on a livecd ubuntu test session?

Tags: live-usb

I am running Ubuntu from a live session in order to see if I can reproduce [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1540553). Since though I'm still supposed to get stuff done, I'm trying to also do that. As a result I have to log onto corporate resources, and lock my screen while I'm not at my desktop.

I set a password on the default ubuntu/999 user account, but Ctrl-Alt-L still does not lock the screen, it merely blacks out the monitor.

How can I have a proper screen lock? Maybe I should just install `xscreensaver`...

Comment: I feel that the fact that I happened to be running Ubuntu+1 here is in no way relevant to the question, or the answer I have provided, since all supported versions of Ubuntu are equally incompatible with `xscreensaver`.

Comment: @DnrDevil That's true, however the issue is also present in Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, so it's not specific to Xenial or due to a bug, it's just how the Live session works.

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu 12.04 & above with Unity/GNOME, you can enable locking the screen with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

However without a password it may not even work or be able to login i would recommend adding a user as well first just in case.

Comment: Also under _System Settings_ → _Security & Privacy_ → _Security_ → _Require my password when_, check _Returning from blank screen_

Comment: Answer still relevant for Ubuntu 18.10 LiveUSB. Enable automatic lock when screen turn off in Settings > Privacy > Screen lock. Don't forget to set a password, also in Settings > Details > Users > Password

Answer (score 1):

Probably not optimal, but it worked.

1. Set up a password from the terminal (the graphical interface didn't work for me, but ymmv).

   ```
   passwd
   ```
2. Open *Software & Updates* and enable all repositories.
3. Install `xscreensaver`.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
   ```
4. Launch the xscreensaver demon. This also opens up a window.

   ```
   xscreensaver
   ```
5. Click on *Settings* and tick *Lock Screen After*. Set your timeout.
6. Open *System Settings* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts*, and add this shortcut:

   ```
   xscreensaver-command -lock
   ```

   Assign to it the key combination of your choice; it's fine to override `ctrl-alt-l`.

Comment: worked on Linux Mint 20.2. have not tested on original Ubuntu, maybe will. Other answer `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false` had seemingly no effect. Interestingly answer `dm-tool lock` from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242110/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-lockscreen-not-working worked kind of (locked the screen but could be circumvented by switching to other tty and on returning back screen was not locked).