# After upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 Lockscreen not working

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

I tried the shortcut Super + L nothing happens.

In the settings, have set lockdown timer for 1 min, nothings happens after that.

In the right corner menu after clicking lock item, it is showing black screen and logging me out.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

shows false.

Comment: Would be nice to merge with https://askubuntu.com/q/1240575/472560

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was having EXACTLY the same problem. It turns out I have several display managers installed, and I was using lightdm instead of gdm3.

You can confirm you are using lightdm if this command works:

```
$ dm-tool lock
```

(But even if that doesn't work you may be using another display manager.)

I got the screen blanking to work properly by configuring gdm3.

Open a terminal and issue this command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Select gdm3 in the list on the terminal, then reboot your system.

Comment: I'd like to credit Zoyolin for the suggestion to use more precise keywords, which led me to this Reddit discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/c41biz/lock_screen_doesnt_work/

Comment: This worked for me too... but as a further question: does this mean that gdm3 is going to be more taxing on the system?

Comment: I am not concerned about it being taxing; if the chosen display manager does not work correctly with a basic feature I think I would be concerned there might be other incompatibilities I had not found yet. I believe I have multiple display managers only because I tried different desktops, and another desktop surely works more correctly with lightdm. I don't know whether lightdm actually IS "lighter" or less taxing than gdm.

Comment: if `dm-tool lock` is working for you, I would just go ahead and update the keyboard shortcut to just that. **Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts**

Comment: `lxlock` failed me running LXDE on top of Ubuntu MATE 20.04, `dm-tool lock` works. Thanks!

Comment: gdm3 is not compatible with nvidia

Comment: @Melchia I don't currently have any nvidia hardware running. Do you have a suggestion to improve my answer?

Comment: Well both lighdm and gdm3 still don't work properly when using an nvidia laptop and multiple monitors.

Comment: Luckily(?) my brother just mailed me a GeForce GT 710 card for my desktop. I just put it in this desktop running Ubuntu 18.04 and gdm3 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4, and it worked fine using the default Nouveau drivers, and I also tried the recommended NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450-server. Works fine with two monitors, and it might even work with all three ports active. What problems should I be looking for?

Comment: @Melchia maybe link to a bug report or another AskUbuntu topic that describes your issue so folks finding this might have a place to look.

Comment: I'm using Nvidia RTX 2070 and gdm3. Seems to be working fine since changing from lightdm

Comment: thank you, now super + L works and also closing the lid locks my laptop

Comment: I recently upgraded Ubuntu Studio 18.04 to 20.04 and I must say so far it seems to have been a mistake.  I had this problem too and tried to follow the steps in this response - `dm-tool lock` worked, but the gdm3 config didn't work at all.  The solution for me was:  in settings manager/keyboard, I added a shortcut for `dm-tool lock` to be associated with SUPER-L.

Comment: This answer works.  I suspect this issue exists due to an oversight of the ubuntu 18.04 -> 20.04 upgrade process.  Ubuntu should have accounted for this during the upgrade.  End users should not need to dig deep like this to troubleshoot the upgrade if ubuntu ever intends to go attract a non-technical audience.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` config and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works

Could you check **Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts** > search(Super+L), this one should be assigned to lock the screen.

The lock is a feature of gnome-session. In your research maybe swap "ubuntu" for "gnome" or "gnome3.36.2" with a bit of luck you have the same as me ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggested keywords -- the keyboard shortcuts part didn't help me, but searching for gnome-session did! I hope one of us helps solve the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't even get to "Settings" on my Ubuntu 20.04 box, probably because I've been updating the same hardware since 12.04.

First I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

... to get "Settings" back. Then I typed:

```
gnome-control-center
```

... to pull settings up.

While I had `Settings` up I right-clicked "Add to Favorites" on the toolbar to keep the `Settings` icon on my desktop.

After that I went to `Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock` to get at all of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved for me by going to

**Settings > Screensaver > Lock Screen**

and then deactivating Lock Screen.

Now everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not the OP's case, but if your `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` shows `true` then you can change it with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

I don't know what set that to false on my system, it was a fresh Ubuntu 23.10 install with GDB display manager.