# Super + L not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

After update from Ubuntu 18 stop working system lock. I'm using gdm3 and nothing helps. `Super + L` and `gnome-screensaver-command -l` not working. After the command screen just blinks one time and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure about the command `gnome-screensaver-command`? This is not available on my 20.04, also an upgraded system (over the interim releases).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I surprised too, but this command exist and trying to lock but not working at all(

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242110/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-lockscreen-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I have faced a similar problem after updating my kali linux. I will guide you how did I solve this because both ubuntu and kali which I used was gnome. 
Steps to resolve:
1. Open your **settings** of gnome. 

[image: Setting]
2. search for **Keyboard shortcuts**

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]
3. Any you have again for **Lock Screen** you have screen icon on right side this time

[image: Lock Screen]
4. Make sure that option is set correctly to **Super+L**, It would be disable during update.

If you feel this is kali screenshot or not comfortable, then you have alternative post to give a check for ubuntu.
[Keyboard shortcut for "Lock screen" not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126782/keyboard-shortcut-for-lock-screen-not-working)

Comment: Already checked, and even tried to bind to something else. Didn't help(

Comment: Is your other keyboard shortcuts working finely ? is your hardware button in laptop or system works properly? if you have.

If those are perfectly working then give a try by reinstall gnome screensaver
<br>

`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-screensaver`

If you still have a problem, Give a try this 

You can re-enable lock screen directly from the terminal.

To see if Lock screen is disabled:

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false`

If result is true then use:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false`

Comment: Nope. Same behavior on any shortcut - screen blink one time and nothing happens. And I've tried to reinstall gs, didn't help( And yes i checked ```disable-lock-screen``` its ```false```.

Comment: The underlying reason why keyboard actions don't work on the desktop with recent versions of Ubuntu is that the desktop icons aren't handled anymore by Nautilus but a GNOME Shell extension called [Desktop Icons](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons) which is part of Ubuntu's default installation (DEB package `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`).

Check this out : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1144

Comment: OMG( But is it possible to lock system from command line?

Comment: It helped) Thx very much.

Comment: ohh Thats great. If you can like the answer that would help me to increase my reputation and gain views to profile 

Thank you.
Regards,
Aravindha Hariharan

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu 20.04, a variation of the solution that @aravindha-hariharan worked for me.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

For me, the value was "true" - the lock screen had been disabled.

So just run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

And verify that it's in fact it's not disabled with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

Note that in my case I do not automatically screen lock. I only manually screen lock with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Screenshot of Gnome Settings ➡️ Privacy ➡️ Lock Screen Settings:

[image: Screenshot of Gnome Settings ➡️ Privacy ➡️ Lock Screen Settings]

Comment: This fixed it. Strange, I don't know what triggered the disabling of lock scrren in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution. I replaced GNOME Shell extension called Desktop Icons (aka @csoriano) with another one (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2452/desktop-icons/) and everything work now.